# How to set object value instead of reference?

Tags: c#

I've asked that question in a different manner and noone answered me, now I'm asking this with an example, hope It's crystal clear what I'm trying to do.

```
List<object> l1 = new List<object>() {"string1", "string2"};
Dictionary<string, object> map = new Dictionary<string, object>();
map.Add("aKey", l1[l1.Count - 1]);
object obj = map["aKey"];
```

What to do with `obj` in order to change `l1[1]` value it currently points to?

`obj = "newString";` will set obj to `"newString"` and leave `l1[1]` - that is `"string2"` unchanged, because object is a reference type. but I don't want that

Or at least get `1` and `l1` out of it.

My whole design is such that I have a storage in the form of two List.

For example you call Engine.Save

Save will get last element from list 2 by default, though if it's given a key as argument it will get the coresponding element from one of the two lists. Than will decide the element's type and save it accordingly or log error message.

I can't easily explain that, nor can I post that much code.

Comment: It is indeed crystal clear that what you are looking for can't be done for immutable types like `string`. Unfortunately "no" is not enough for good SO answer, but since question does not provide reason of the request it is very hard to give any better answer. So chances of getting question answered in current state are quite low.

Comment: As hinted at by Alexei's comment, to achieve a similar effect, you'll want to use a mutable type instead.  If you explain the need behind your request, I'm sure you'll be provided with acceptable design workarounds.

Comment: Just leave `obj` alone and ask `map` to update its value at `"aKey"`.

Comment: @Tamas Hegedus that will update its value, not the one in the list.

Comment: Well right, I didn't pay sufficient attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dictionary, you could store a reference to the list and the index separately, using tuples:

```
// Set up the list.
var myList = new List<object>() {"string1", "string2"};

// Set up the dictionary.
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<List<object>, int>>();
myDict.Add("myKey", new Tuple<List<object>, int>>(myList, myList.Count - 1));

// Update the list by using the dictionary.
var theTuple = myDict["myKey"];
var theList = theTuple.Item1;
var theIndex = theTuple.Item2;
theList[theIndex] = "newString";
```